# Ошибка при создании глобального соединения socket python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

Код:

```
host="ххх.ххх.хх.хх"
port = 4444
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
```

При выполнении данного участка кода(и ввода глобального IP), возникает ошибка:

```
line 13, in <module>
s.bind((host,port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен.
```

При этом с локальными подключениями все работает. Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Эта ошибка означает, что вы используете ip, который не принадлежит этому хосту .

Comment: можете , пожалуйста, обьяснить подробнее, тк я использовал свой IP

Comment: ip, который вы пробуете использовать не назначен ни одному сетевому интерфейсу на хосте, на котором вы это запускаете. Если у вас windows, проверте вывод `ipconfig`. Если linux, macos - `ifconfig`. Это покажет вам все ваши интерфейсы и их ip адреса. Есть там этот ip?

Comment: я использовал IP который мне показал сайт ip-ping, при команде ipconfig появляются только локальные IP адреса.

Comment: В этом и дело, вы можете использовать только локальные адреса. Вы не можете слушать ip, который вам не пренадлежит. Почитайте тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286211/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-host-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-createserver-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-htt/1286305#1286305

Comment: хорошо,спасибо,подскажи,пожалуйста, как тогда вообще создать глобальное соединение с помощью socket

Comment: Глобальное - никак. На хосте слушать локальный ip, а с роутера/прокси (или что там у вас) пробрасывать порт. В том ответе, что я выше дал, описано же

Comment: хорошо поставлю вопрос по другому, возможно ли соеденить с помощью socket два пк не в одной сети, и если нет то как это сделать на питоне в целом

Comment: Два пк не в одной сети не могут между собой взаимодействовать напрямую никак. Могут только через посредника. В простом случае (вы в локальной сети, она через роутер подключена к интренету) таким постредником является этот роутер и все решается настройкой forward-a портов. Какая у вас конфигурация, что за сети, я не знаю, чтоб посоветовать, как в вашей ситуации это можно решить.

Comment: возможно ли открыть сервер, и к нему подключиться уже из глобальной сети?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: я очень далек от web разработки, но в ней насколько я знаю создается сервер(сайт) к которому можно подключиться из глобальной сети

Comment: Можно купить виртуальный сервер с реальным IP (цены от ~5$/мес), см. digitalocean или linode. Мне не вполне понятно, почему вам не подходит вариант с настройкой роутера.

Comment: я не умею делать настройку роутера, и впринципе не понимаю , как тогда возможно подключение например чатов? чаты же по сути два глобал пк

Comment: Чаты обычно работают через сервер. Т.е. клиент из вашей локальной сети подсоединяется к серверу доступному глобально, и другой клиент так же. Есть программы (типа торрент клиентов), которые умеют сами настраивать роутер. Ищите по uPNP